# Django templates issue

Tags: django-templates

## I have installed django current version with venv I facing an issue with templates when I'm creating index.html this show an truncatechar_html suggestion in place of html:5 while I have setup everythig properly.

**I'm trying for creating index.html file inside of templates folder in my django app during that I'm getting truncatechar_html suggestion in place of html:5**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.